# Selection tableView inside TableView Cell - didSelectRowAt in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

[image]

1. when i select tableview cell inside tableview
2. why same row select in different cell

my code is -

```
 var isSelectedIndex = 0
 var isIndexSelected = false


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        if tableView.tag == 101{
            
            let indentifier:String = "AuditQuestionsTblCell"
            var cell : AuditQuestionsTblCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: indentifier) as? AuditQuestionsTblCell
            if (cell == nil){
                let nib:Array = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AuditQuestionsTblCell", owner: nil, options: nil)! as [Any]
                cell = nib[0] as? AuditQuestionsTblCell
            }
            cell?.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none
            cell?.backgroundColor = (UIColor.clear)
            
            cell?.tblViewAnswer.delegate = self
            cell?.tblViewAnswer.dataSource = self
            
            TotalAuditQuetionCount = arrParentGroup.count
            
            return cell!
        }else{
            let indentifier:String = "AnswerTblCell"
            var cell : AnswerTblCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: indentifier) as? AnswerTblCell
            if (cell == nil){
                let nib:Array = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AnswerTblCell", owner: nil, options: nil)! as [Any]
                cell = nib[0] as? AnswerTblCell
            }
            cell?.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none
            cell?.backgroundColor = (UIColor.clear)
            
            if arrOptionList.count>0{
                let dictOption = arrOptionList[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
                cell?.lblTitle.text = dictOption.valueForNullableKey(key: "option")
                
                strfailureReasonRequired = dictOption.valueForNullableKey(key: "failure_reason_required")
                
                cell?.btnSelectedOption.tag = indexPath.row
                cell?.btnSelectedOption.addTarget(self, action: #selector(methodOptionSelection(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
                
                if isSelectedIndex == indexPath.row && self.isIndexSelected == true
                {
                    cell?.viewOption.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
                }
                else
                {
                    cell?.viewOption.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
                }
            }
            
            return cell!
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if self.isSelectedIndex == indexPath.row && self.isIndexSelected == true{
            self.isIndexSelected = false
        }else{
            self.isIndexSelected = true
        }
        self.isSelectedIndex = indexPath.row
        self.tblViewAudit.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: yes it's a question

Comment: You need to save the whole `IndexPath` that is selected; `row` and `section`, not just the row.

Comment: Have you checked with something like `if tableView.tag == 101`?

Comment: @Paulw11 how can i use section in this case

Comment: @ToseefKhilji yes i checked

Comment: You compare the `isSelectedIndex == indexpath.row` but this will match the relevant row in any section. Store the `IndexPath` not just the row and then compare `selectedIndexPath == indexPath`

Comment: it's done on my side....... thank you @Paulw11 and Toseefkhilji.